Meaning of "auch" in "auch schon"
I have read/heard the following text in https://slowgerman.com/2024/10/01/buchpreisbindung/:

Stell dir vor, du bist in Deutschland und möchtest ein Buch kaufen.
Sagen wir einen Bestseller. Du gehst in einen Buchladen – das Buch
kostet 9 Euro. Du gehst in einen Supermarkt – das Buch kostet 9 Euro.
Du schaust bei Amazon im Internet – das Buch kostet 9 Euro. Hast du
dich auch schon gefragt, warum das so ist?

Google Translate and DeepL translator translate the last sentence as:
Have you ever wondered why that is?
"auch", which means "too" / "as well", is dropped in the translation to English. I assume it is a modal particle here. What does it mean?

I would read the "auch" in this case literally:

Hast du dich auch schon gefragt, warum das so ist?
Have you, too, ever asked yourself why it's like that?

The phrase insinuates that other people (maybe including the speaker) already asked themselves this question. You'll run into phrases like this occasionally, for example in promotional contexts, "teasers" and the like.
It's everybody's guess why the AI translation just drops it.

Likely because English native speakers would never use "too" in a sentence like that. The people referenced by "too" in English are usually explicit. A possible example in English: "I have always wondered why that is. Have you ever wondered it too?"

In this occurrence, the word "auch" presupposes that there are other people who have already wondered about that. It's a stylistic device to make the reader feel they are being drawn into an ongoing lively discussion. (I'd say it's a manipulative attempt to make the dull question of book prices appear more relevant and "interesting".)
There is a use of "auch" as a modal particle that occurs in questions, and this may create an ambiguity. For example: "Hast du auch deine Zähne geputzt?" As a presuppositional particle (in the sense above), it reflects the fact that there are more people who brushed their teeth, or that more things have been cleaned besides the teeth. In this use, "auch" can be stressed if it follows the word that it associates with ("Hast du deine Zähne AUCH geputzt?" = the teeth and other things). –– As a modal particle, it cannot be stressed, and the pronunciation would be: "Hast du auch deine ZÄHNE GEPUTZT?" (this coresponds to the neutral sentence accent that applies to the predicate "Zähen putzen" as a close unit). This modal particle would mean: "You know you have to do this, so did you?" So, as far as I can tell, it always refers to a task in the context that has to be fulfilled. For your example this doesn't quite make sense. And in your example, I would imagine "auch" is pronounced with stress.
